# What part of the url is host?

Tags: url

As per this doc

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986

what is the host in the url below?

```
https://www.drive.google.com
```

is the host `drive.google` or just `google`?

Comment: Are you talking about window.location.hostname? That would be `drive.google.com`

Answer (score 3):

> The host subcomponent of authority is identified by an IP literal
> encapsulated within square brackets, an IPv4 address in dotted-
> decimal form, or a registered name.

The entire `www.drive.google.com` string is the registered name that points to an IP address. That is the host component of the URI.